# calling windows form control library using MapPoint from an MVVMLight WPF app on a x64 machine

Tags: wpf, forms, controls, mvvm-light, mappoint

MapPoint can be used within a WPF application, if a AxMapPoint object is 
incorporated into a Windows Form Control Library.

Creating a simple test app, with the following body in MainWindows.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">     
    <Grid Name="mapControl" Loaded="MapPointControl_Loaded"/>
</Grid>
```

works when a WPF project is created.  The CodeBehind function call 
looks like this.

```
private void MapPointControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
                // Create the interop host control.
                System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost host =
                    new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();


                //  mpControl = new 
                MapPointControl userControl = new MapPointControl();
                host.Child = userControl;

                // Add the interop host control to the Grid
                // control's collection of child controls.
                this.mapControl.Children.Add(host);

        } catch { }
```

This works for a WPF project,

However, creating a MVVM project, doesn't work.

A failure occurs  at this line

```
                MapPointControl userControl = new MapPointControl();
```

The following Dialog Box appears

> FileNotFoundException was caught
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.MapPoint, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture= neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'  or one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.
>
> ( Interop.MapPoint.dll exists in the bin/Debug folder )

in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

[Enable Fusion log viewer](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx) and share the result. It should tell you what dependency is missing.

1. Click Start-> Enter "fusion" and right click on **Fusion Log Viewer** to Run As Administrator.
2. Click Settings-> Log bind failures to disk.
3. Trigger the exception, then click "Refresh" in the log viewer.
4. Click "View Log" on the entry that appears in Fusion. Share back the results.

Comment: *** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (03/05/2012 @ 10:31:41 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x8007000b. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\verifeye\markV\viewer4\Viewer\bin\Debug\Viewer.vshost.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = verifeye-LTE\verifeye
LOG: DisplayName = Interop.MapPoint, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)

Comment: LOG: User = verifeye-LTE\verifeye
LOG: DisplayName = Interop.MapPoint, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/verifeye/markV/viewer4/Viewer/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = Viewer.vshost.exe
Calling assembly : WindowsFormsControlLibraryMapPoint, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

Comment: ===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\verifeye\markV\viewer4\Viewer\bin\Debug\Viewer.vshost.exe.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/verifeye/markV/viewer4/Viewer/bin/Debug/Interop.MapPoint.DLL.

Comment: LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\verifeye\markV\viewer4\Viewer\bin\Debug\Interop.MapPoint.dll
LOG: Entering run-from-source setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: Interop.MapPoint, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.

Comment: I tried the same executable within the debugger on a 32-bit Windows 7 machine, it ran without any problems.

Comment: Is your [project build targeting](http://visualstudiohacks.com/articles/visual-studio-net-platform-target-explained/) **Any Platform** or **x86-only**?

Comment: I targeted Any Platform,  as you suggested, targeting x86-only is working now. When I built a test app without MVVM Light, I can use Any Platform.  I don't know enough about MVVM Light, what is restricting the build to X86-only?

Comment: This sounds like it could be an issue with **MVVM Light** - you should [post an issue in the project website](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic).